# Does Masterful optimization face alters the model's weights?

Tags: keras

I would like some clarification about the Masterful API. Which is the difference between the optimization face and the regularization/training face?. They mention:

> Optimization means finding the best weights for a model and training
> data.

Does this imply that the optimization phace alters the model’s weight? Or is it only about finding the best hyperparameter set up?.